# Best ways to make a pointer point to nothing

Tags: c, pointers

We all know popular NULL assignments for pointers like:

```
int *p = NULL;
```

or

```
int *p = 0;
```

where we always are supposed to check the pointer value before dereferencing it in order to prevent your program from crashing down.

1.) But are there any better ways to nullify pointers?

2.) I know the following statement is no way different (but nonsense) to nullify a pointer as it will just write '0' to the pointer variable but someone told me to use it for better code compiler compatibility. Is it true? I don't think it makes any sense?

```
memset(&p, 0, size(p));
```

Comment: To write zeroes to the pointer variable it would be `memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p))`, but yes, it is a nonsense, and non-portable, too, because the `NULL` pointer is not required to be an all-bits-zero binary value.

Comment: `int *p = 0;` does not necessarily write an all zero bit pattern to `p`.  It will certainly write some null pointer value.  `p` is a pointer, not an integer.

Comment: This sounds like a solution seeking for a problem. What is your issue with using `NULL` (don't use `0` in C; it is allowed, but bad practice, as it is in C++).

Comment: Actually, the `memset` version is incorrect, the pointer representation of `NULL` is not guaranteed to be `0`. But it is guaranteed that casting a `0` literal to a pointer gives the correct underlying machine representation. `= NULL` / `== NULL` is the only safe way.

Comment: @Kevin: Casting `0` to a pointer other than `void *` actually is not guaranteed to yield a _null pointer_. But it is hidden that before the cast is applied, the integer constant `0` is converted to a _null pointer_. Which renders the cast very useless. That's why one should use `NULL` which is typically (and by good practice) `#define NULL ((void *)0)` to allow for a warning when used as an integer in the standard headers.

Comment: Are you looking to obfuscate your code or something? Then you can think of more fancy ways of producing `0`s..

Comment: Thank you all. I know most of you guys are frustrated with this. But to be honest, I also know that the former technique is much clear and obviously the later is confusing and NONSENSE. Someone told me to use the memset thingy for which I just thought of asking whether he really had some point in it which I am not aware of.

Comment: The `memset()` approach makes sense for applying `0` to an _array_ of pointers.  Yet a single pointer: Using `int *p = NULL;` is understood by all non-journeymen C programmers.

Comment: @Olaf , can u explain a little bit more in detail when you say "But it is hidden that before the cast is applied, the integer constant 0 is converted to a null pointer. Which renders the cast very useless."

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: See 6.3.2.3p3 in the standard.

Comment: @chux: As you previously stated, a _null pointer_ is not necessary represented by all bits zero. So `memset` actually does not make much sense in a standard way. In fact the function is of little use for anything else than to nullify an array of integers or to set an array of `char` to an arbitrary value. Anything else is implementation-specific. A good compiler should be able to use an optimised version for a `for ... *p++ = NULL;` loop, possibly call `memset`, but that leaves the source code standard compliant.

Comment: @Olaf, do not disagree with "`memeset()` ...  standard way".  `memset()` is certainly useful in  implementation specific code. BTW: think you meant " ... set an array of `unsigned char`..."

Comment: @Olaf: Casting a _constant_ `0` to any pointer type _is_ guaranteed to yield a null pointer. From 6.3.2.3p3: _An integer constant expression with the value 0 [...] is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed [...]_. Nowhere is the requirement to cast to `void*` first.

Comment: @chux: I wanted to cut down the comment a bit. You can set a `char` array to any positive value, negative values involve implementation defined behaviour once more:-)

Comment: @rodrigo: That conversion of the integer constant `0` is some of the legacy rubbish which should really be removed asap. Simply because this implies e.g. `1-1` must not yield a warning and is a valid _null pointer constant_, although no sane programmer would use it other than for an integer calculation. Just leave it at that it's a bad style to use `0` for a pointer and either rely on implicit conversion to a boolean for conditionals or use the macro `NULL` explicitly. Until they follow Pascal, etc. (including C++) with something like `nullptr`, `nil` or similar.

Comment: @Olaf I thought only `unsigned char` was defined to not have padding.  So setting a `char` (which may be signed) via `memset()` may write the wrong value to a padding bit resulting in UB. 6.2.6.2 1.  IAC, Writing performance / portable code is hard.  Good engineering is about finding the middle ground that satisfies most yet alerts when it can't.

Comment: @chux: See [6.2.5p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p6) and p5. And `char` is guraranteed not to include padding (otherwise you could not `memcpy`). Not sure why they use `unsigned char` for these function, maybe to avoid the indeterminate signedness with unsigned integers being less implementation-specific. As I see it, the standard already tries to replace the `char` by a byte and `char *` by `void *` in some functions. But it is all very slowly not to break legacy code - too slow IMHO.

Comment: @Olaf Suspect `char ` is avoided as `memset(&some_char, 128, 1)` may set a trap value.  Hmm, I think we've taken this chat a bit far off course.  Happy trails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best ways to make a pointer point to nothing

```
int *p = NULL;
```

---

`NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` as an implementation-defined *null pointer constant*.  A given implementation may have multiple *null pointer constants*

All  *null pointer constants* will compare to `0` and each other.  `*p = 0;` will also set `p` to a *null pointer constant*, typically the same as `*p = NULL;`

> But are there any better way to nullify your pointers?

There are other ways but not better.

Some style guides promote  `*p = 0;`.  What is most important is to convey code clarity.  Use the style of your group's coding standards. Best to have uniformity in your group's style.

---

`memset(p, 0, size(p));` is wrong.  Should be `memset(&p, 0, size(p));` to zero fill `p`.  [@rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35874836/best-ways-to-make-a-pointer-point-to-nothing/35875470#comment59413337_35874836)

Comment: Interesting. So, say, `(intptr_t) (void *) 0 != (intptr_t) (void *) NULL` would be compliant?

Comment: @doynax Yes.  Yet consider `void *p1 = 0; void *p2 = NULL;`  and `(intptr_t) p1 == (intptr_t) p2` and `memcmp(&p1, &p2, sizeo p1) != 0` is possible too.  The bit patterns of various _null pointers_ need not match.  Their conversion to a `intptr_t` may (or may not) fold these null pointers to a common value.  A conversion of pointer --> `intptr_t` --> pointer need not result in the same bit pattern, but to an equivalent pointer.

Comment: I suppose that rules out using uintptr_t for xor-linked-lists in portable C code. Bummer.

Comment: @doynax Yes it does rule it out - in general.  Might be possible to construct such code that is specified to work on a large sub-set of platforms.  Lots of highly-portable code contains `#if` or `assert()` because it just cannot work everywhere per spec.  For all but trivial coding, sometimes it is not possible to create worthwhile 100% portable code.  Yet each compromise is a step on the [road to perdition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perdition).

Comment: @chux , So in a nutshell NULL keyword should better be used for null pointer checks. Right?

Comment: @AKay `NULL`, a _macro_, not keyword,  can be used for null pointer checks and for null pointer assignments.

Comment: Thanks @chux, and we should not use it for checking whether any integer variable holds 0 value. Right?

Comment: @AKay Agreed.  Comparing `NULL` (if defined as a pointer type) to an integer does not meet the constraints of the C spec's  _Equality operators_ `==` and `!=` which results in UB.  Most compilers will handle such a comparison as one might expect, yet it is still not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @chux